# How to open any URL taken from User in Web Browser in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to open the URL entered by user but clicking on the button the app is not responding.

The Java Snippet of What i have done is :-

```
 e=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 final String s=e.getText().toString();
 browser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(s));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your stack trace here

Comment: `if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
   url = "http://" + url;` 
You need to add **http://**

Comment: validate your url, then create your intent...

Comment: First thing is that you need to get your editText's string on the onClick method of button and then you need to validate the url before using intent on it.

Answer (score 2):

You initialised `s` when EditText was empty. So add below line in OnClick() method to get user input-
    String s=e.getText().toString();

```
    browser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    browser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String s=e.getText().toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(s));
            startActivity(i);
    }
});
```